# Can I use a phrase 'financial relief' in an essay? Does this phrase make sense in english?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, phrase-choice

This option brings a financial relief particularly to the owners of uninsured pets.

Comment: Do you mean 'financial relief' as in a payment(s)? or just relief from financial pressures?

Comment: Financial relief as in lower costs of treatment.

Comment: It's syntactically valid either way, but we wouldn't *normally* include the article when talking about ***bringing financial relief*** to someone. This preference is even stronger in contexts using the "bare" noun with no modifying adjective, as in *This medicine brings / offers / gives **relief** to people with hay fever.*

Answer (score -1):

It's completely fine to use that. But if I were you, I'd have explored other options such as 'eased the financial burden,' etc.